# ¿Base de datos dinámica?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Estaba intentando hacer una web sencilla dónde ver productos (Televisores, móviles, etc) La duda me surge al diseñar la base de datos(mysql), yo había pensado hacer una tabla para cada producto pero no creo que sea una opción muy eficiente ya que si el administrador de la web quiere añadir un producto que no tenga una tabla no podría.

Creo que la solución es mediante columnas dinámicas y campos personalizados, pero no sé por dónde empezar.

**Actualización de la pregunta**
Los productos se clasificarían por categoría, un producto solo puede pertenecer a una categoría. Todos los productos tienen algunos campos fijos pero dependiendo de que producto sea tendrán unos campos diferentes (por ejemplo, un televisor puede tener un campo para ver si es pantalla curva y un móvil otro campo para ver el sistema operativo)
¿Hay alguna forma de que estos campos no estén predefinidos y que la estructura de la base de datos relacional prevea la posibilidad de definir estos 'campos personalizados'?

Estoy utilizando Laravel 6 junto a mysql.

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: hola buen día me tome la liberta de buscar el concepto de "bases de datos dinámicas" , encontré esto  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=base+de+datos+dinamica+caracteristicas  dale un vistazo espero te ayude con tu duda

Comment: Tu pregunta no es muy clara. Quizá con una tabla `producto` bastaría. Luego, puedes usar IDs por ejemplo si quieres identificar los productos por áreas, creando una relación de la tabla `producto` con otra tabla cualquiera del modelo. Eso se llama aplicar el concepto de base de datos relacional. Si eso no te sirve explica mejor el problema y qué entiendes por base de datos dinámica.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta para aclarar mis dudas

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia conviene cheques [ask] o puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Creo que deberías buscar un curso de diseño de bases de datos. O al menos alguien que te explique lo básico. Lo que preguntas es simplemente algo que dificilmente tiene éxito en el mundo real. Dejo una historia (en inglés) de una implementación de base de datos dinámica y sus horrores https://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/

Answer (score 0):

Quizás puede ser algo más simple implementar una tabla de productos y que televisor, móvil, etc, sea un tipo de producto, algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE productos
(
id INT NOT NULL,
nombre_producto VARCHAR(50),
marca_produscto VARCHAR(50),
tipo_producto VARCHAR(20),
...
PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

ya cuando filtres el producto por tu web iría por tipo en caso que necesites ver una lista de moviles o televisores disponibles.

Comment: Bueno, ya con la segunda parte añadida a la pregunta esto no sirve de mucho...

Answer (score 0):

Deberias analizar tu modelo de dominio. Un Producto tiene campos en comun a todos los productos y dependiendo tu modelo (no se que estas construyendo) habra campos que correspondan a producto en particular.

Hay dos opciones:

1. Agregar todos los posibles campos en la misma tabla y hacerlos NULLABLE para que los que no se usen sean "opcionales". Esta es la mas fácil de implementar pero la menos optima.
2. Crear una tabla de "Claves-Valor" para los datos opcionales, donde 'Clave' identifica el atributo y debe predefinirse en el codigo de tu programa y "Valor" ser{a el dato . Esta es la recomendable pero es mas compleja de programar.

Espero sirva!

Comment: Gracias! Me podrías dar un poco mas de info sobre la segunda opción?

Comment: Seguro, el concepto esta descripto en [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

Hay una discusion sobre Maria DB donde recomiendan incluso una tercer [solucion](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/entity-attribute-value-implementation/) mas compleja pero mucho mas interesante y moderna. 

Basicamente busca EAV (Entity Attibute Model) en internet y vas a encontrar toneladas de info y discusion sobre el tema.